# Graph Neural Network Custom Data

Tags: graph, neural-network, pytorch-geometric, gnn

I following this tutorial.
https://colab.research.google.com/github/AntonioLonga/PytorchGeometricTutorial/blob/main/Tutorial3/Tutorial3.ipynb
I want to try it on custom dataset. How do I use my own dataset instead of Cora ? I would love any idea.